# PHP OOP Getting started

Tags: php, oop, object

I have always been "scared" of OOP, i understand the classes, functions and constructors as I use classes in a java based language called Processing at University.

However, I am unsure how to go about adopting OOP into the code I use, could someone please direct me to a good some good tutorials where I can learn about it. I'm really interested in web technologies and always use PHP for backend processing but I would like to also improve my knowledge of it as I belive I am at the stage where I can progress to more advanced things... such as OOP.

Thanks

Comment: You will find a lot when just searching for [php tutorial oop](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+tutorial+oop). Please also see the related links right hand.

Comment: A word of caution, however. Patterns may look cool, but don't force them into code. Forcing OOP patterns into code can make it more complicated, especially if the wrong pattern is used. Keep things simple and only apply patterns when the pattern starts showing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could recommend this books:

[PHP Objects and Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143022925X)

[PHP Object-Oriented Solutions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210117)

also you can invest in some good video tutorials like lynda.com's PHP Beyond Basics:

[PHP Beyond Basics](http://www.lynda.com/tutorial/653?srchtrk=index:5%0Alinktypeid:2%0Aq:php%0Apage:1%0As:relevance%0Asa:true%0Aproducttypeid:2)

Comment: Nice recursive link there for the PHP Objects and Patterns book! ;-)

Comment: you can get these videos on torrent sites as well (I didn't say that =))

Comment: good link both of you +1 but voting to close.

Comment: THe link to the book did not work. Thanks for the link to lynda, however at the moment I am more interested in free tutroails :)

Answer (score 3):

I would start with reviewing the PHP manuals [pages on OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/oop5.intro.php). Then maybe consider investigating [design patterns](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns).

Answer (score 2):

If you understand the basics of OOP, you are at the point to start learning about design patterns. A book like "Head First Design Patterns" from O'Reilly, will get you started.

Answer (score 1):

As in any language it's important to get familiar with design patterns. Some are very practical and are used constantly to tackle and approach typical problems.

Although you could do an easy search on "php design patterns", [this one](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-designptrns/) coverts some basic patterns which are used often.

Besides the above, I'd just like to say that you have to start using OOP! I believe that experience is a very, very important aspect of learning OOP, and to use it correctly in every situation.

Comment: yeah I attempted to learn about it a while back, but got put off as i started getting confused, that was a couple years back now and want to make another crack at it. :)